# Why do I get SQL exception when calling a .Net WCF Service?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf

I created a simple application in .Net which has a service that can perform CRUD operations on a database (Add, Delete, Get).

My problem is that when I call a method from the repository like "Add a new object" the operation performs with no problems but when I call the the service method that adds a new object to the database, it runs for about a minute doing nothing, then I get the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

The method from the service just calls the repository to add that object.

Here is the code where I call the services(all of them have this problem):

```
using DataLayer.Entities;
using DataLayer.Implementation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WfcConsumer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceReference1.ClientServiceClient clientService = new ServiceReference1.ClientServiceClient();
            ServiceReference2.ProductServiceClient productService = new ServiceReference2.ProductServiceClient();
            ServiceReference3.StoreServiceClient storeService = new ServiceReference3.StoreServiceClient();
            ServiceReference5.SupplierServiceClient supplierService = new ServiceReference5.SupplierServiceClient();

            Store store = new Store();
            Product product = new Product();
            Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
            Client client = new Client();
            client.Username = "test";
            client.Parola = "123";
            client.Email = "abcd@yahoo.com";
            client.clientId = 2;

            store.Name = "amazon";
            store.StoreId = 1;

            product.Name = "laptop";
            product.ProductId = 3;
            product.Price = 50000;
            Console.WriteLine("the begining");
            supplier.categorie = "IT";
            supplier.name = "walmart";
            supplier.SupplierId = 2;

            Console.WriteLine("client");
            clientService.Add(client);
            Console.WriteLine("product");
            productService.Add(product);
            Console.WriteLine("store");
            storeService.Add(store);
            Console.WriteLine("supplier");
            supplierService.Add(supplier);
            Console.WriteLine("The end");
        }
    }
}
```

One of the service class I used:

```
using DataLayer;
using DataLayer.Entities;
using DataLayer.Implementation;
using HelloWCF.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HelloWCF.Implementation
{
    public class ClientService : IClientService
    {
        public  ClientRepository c = new ClientRepository();

        public void Add(Client obj)
        {
            c.Add(obj);
        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            c.Delete(id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Client> GetAll()
        {
            return c.GetAll();
        }

        public Client GetById(int id)
        {
            return c.GetById(id);
        }

        public void Update(int id, Client obj)
        {
            c.Update(id, obj);
        }
    }
}
```

And the repository class for the above service:

```
using DataLayer.Entities;
using DataLayer.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataLayer.Implementation
{
     public class ClientRepository : IClientRepository
     {
            ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext();

            public void Add(Client obj)
            {
                db.Clients.Add(obj);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            public void Delete(int id)
            {
                var obj = db.Clients.ElementAt(id);
                db.Clients.Remove(obj);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            public IEnumerable<Client> GetAll()
            {
                return db.Clients.ToList();
            }

            public Client GetById(int id)
            {
                return db.Clients.ElementAt(id);
            }

            public void Update(int id, Client obj)
            {
                var _obj = db.Clients.ElementAt(id);
                _obj.clientId = obj.clientId;
                _obj.Email = obj.Email;
                _obj.Nume = obj.Nume;
                _obj.Parola = obj.Parola;
                _obj.Store = obj.Store;
                _obj.Username = obj.Username;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea why it works fine when I call the repository directly but when I call the service it gives me this exception?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: `The server was not found or was not accessible`. Are you sure your connection string doesn't use relative path?

Comment: Try connecting to the SQL server with the given Server, username and password. Because EF is not able to connect to the SQL Server.

Comment: I use the database that visual studio provides and did not make any changes to the default settings.